# How to set src to each shuffled image in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to shuffle images from array to a specific div.

```html
<body>
  <div id="set"></div>
</body>

<script>
  var ArrayOfImages = ['bar.jpg',
    'foo.jpg',
    'koo.jpg',
    'too.jpg'
  ];

  var set = document.getElementById("set");

  set.addEventListener("click", randomize, false);


  ArrayOfImages.forEach(function(image) {
    var elem = document.createElement('img');
    elem.src = image;
    set.appendChild(elem);
  });


  function shuffle(array) {
    let counter = array.length;


    // While there are elements in the array`enter code here`
    while (counter > 0) {
      // Pick a random index
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

      // Decrease counter by 1
      counter--;

      // And swap the last element with it
      let temp = array[counter];
      array[counter] = array[index];
      array[index] = temp;
    }

    return array;
  }

  function randomize() {
    set.innerHTML = shuffle(ArrayOfImages);
  }
</script>
```

Now the problem is, that `innerHTML` only changes the text of the image but cannot set an `src` to it. Though it does the shuffle.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Replace `set.innerHTML = shuffle(ArrayOfImages);` with `ArrayOfImages = shuffle(ArrayOfImages);`

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` will change the actual HTML, not the images `src` which is what you want to change.

At the moment you are getting your image elements from your HTML using

`document.getElementById('set)`

however, you HTML can only have one element with the `id` set. Thus, you can use the `class` attribute instead to give multiple elements the identifier of 'set' and get all your image elements using:

`document.getElementsByClassName('set')`

which will return a collection of your HTML image tags. Now, to change each image's source you can loop over this collection or loop over your shuffled images and set each image's source.

See an example below for further clarification:

```js
var img_elems = document.getElementsByClassName('set'); // Get all elements to set the image to

// To go into your randomize() function:

// Shuffled images returned via your shuffle() function
var shuffled_images = ['https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350', 'https://www.pandotrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Seigantoji-Pagoda-and-Nachi-Falls-in-Nacho-Japan.jpg', 'https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg'];

for (var i = 0; i < shuffled_images.length; i++) {
  img_elems[i].src = shuffled_images[i]; // Set the image to the src value.
}
```

```css
/* Ignore this */

img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="" class="set" /><br />
<img src="" class="set" /><br />
<img src="" class="set" />
```

Answer (score 0):

More clean and better way of doing it in vanilla javascript.
The issue was in your shuffle function.

```
var image_swap_tool = function(options){
    var self = this;
    self.ArrayOfImages = options.ArrayOfImages;
    self.image_container_elem = document.getElementById("set");
    self.image_container_elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
        self.randomize();
    });
}

image_swap_tool.prototype.create_image = function(){
    var self = this;
    var images = self.ArrayOfImages;
    var image_container = self.image_container_elem;
    image_container.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i=0; i < images.length;i++){
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src',images[i]);
        image_container.appendChild(img);
    }
};

image_swap_tool.prototype.shuffle = function(){
    var self = this;
    var images = self.ArrayOfImages;
    let counter = images.length;
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;
        // And swap the last element with it
        let temp = images[counter];
        images[counter] = images[index];
        images[index] = temp;
    }
    //Set new order back to images for next time
    self.ArrayOfImages = images;
    //Images are shuffled then append them again
    self.create_image();
}

image_swap_tool.prototype.randomize = function(){
    var self = this;
    var image_container = self.image_container_elem;
    self.shuffle();
}

var options = {};
options.ArrayOfImages = ['bar.jpg', 'foo.jpg', 'koo.jpg', 'too.jpg'];
var tool = new image_swap_tool(options);
tool.create_image();
```

Thanks